# Azure SDK for TableStorage with .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am searching for some examples or documentation on how to use the Azure SDK to store and retrieve data in Azure Table Storage.

I use C# with .NET 4.5 framework.

I found https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/ documentation here.

the part:

```
// Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");

// Create a new customer entity.
CustomerEntity customer1 = new CustomerEntity("Harp", "Walter");
customer1.Email = "Walter@contoso.com";
customer1.PhoneNumber = "425-555-0101";

// Create the TableOperation that inserts the customer entity.
TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(customer1);

// Execute the insert operation.
table.Execute(insertOperation);
```

is not available anymore.

Does anybody know how to do this with .NET 4.5?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine. While the documentation mentions version 2.0, this points to the version of the storage SDK and not the version of .NET.

**Edit:**

In order to get the GetTableReference method you need to do the following:

- Reference Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll version 2.0.0.0 or higher (via NuGet: `Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage`)
- Add the following namespaces:

---

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
```

- Initialize the storage account and the table client.

---

```
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(...);
var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
```

Comment: There is defenitly no getTableReference() method for tableClient or CloudTable class! Which .NET Version did you used?

Comment: I wrote a blog post a few days ago covering some simple examples about using storage client library 2.0 which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/17/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-table-storage-code/. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

This is my table storage manager class, i am using .NET 4.5

```
public class TableStorageManager
{
    private CloudTableClient TableClient;
    private CloudTable Table;

    #region Sigleton implementation

    public TableStorageManager(string tablename)
    {
        TableClient = StorageFactory.GetCloudStorageAccount().CreateCloudTableClient();
        Table = TableClient.GetTableReference(tablename);
        //var ctx = TableClient.GetTableServiceContext();

        Table.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    #endregion

    public void InsertAnyEntity<T>(T entity)
    {
        var translatedEntity = Helper.ConvertToDictionaryEntity<T>(entity);
        InsertEntity<DictionaryEntity>(translatedEntity);
    }
    public void InsertEntity<T>(T entity) where T : ITableEntity
    {
        Table.Execute(TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity));
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(TableQuery<T> query) where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        return Table.ExecuteQuery(query);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetEntities<T>(String partitionKey, Int32 noOfRecords ) where T : ITableEntity, new()
    {
        var query = new TableQuery<T>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey));
        var result = Table.ExecuteQuery(query).Take(noOfRecords).ToList();
        return result;
    }

    public T GetEntity<T>(String partitionKey, String rowKey) where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        var retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey);

        // Execute the retrieve operation.
        var retrievedResult = Table.Execute(retrieveOperation);
        return retrievedResult.Result as T;
    }

    public Boolean DeleleEntity<T>(String partitionKey, String rowKey) where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey);

        // Execute the operation.
        var retrievedResult = Table.Execute(retrieveOperation);

        // Assign the result to a CustomerEntity.
        var deleteEntity = (T)retrievedResult.Result;

        // Create the Delete TableOperation.
        if (deleteEntity != null)
        {
            TableOperation deleteOperation = TableOperation.Delete(deleteEntity);

            // Execute the operation.
            Table.Execute(deleteOperation);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public Boolean UpdateEntity<T>(String partitionKey, String rowKey) where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey);

        // Execute the operation.
        TableResult retrievedResult = Table.Execute(retrieveOperation);

        // Assign the result to a CustomerEntity object.
        var updateEntity = (T)retrievedResult.Result;

        if (updateEntity != null)
        {
            // Create the InsertOrReplace TableOperation
            TableOperation updateOperation = TableOperation.Replace(updateEntity);

            // Execute the operation.
            Table.Execute(updateOperation);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public Boolean UpdateEntity<T>(T entity) where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        Boolean isUpdate = false;
        try
        {
            // Create the InsertOrReplace TableOperation
            TableOperation updateOperation = TableOperation.Replace(entity);

            // Execute the operation.
            Table.Execute(updateOperation);
            isUpdate = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isUpdate = false;
        }

        return isUpdate;
    }
}
```